# object property for a class

Tags: java, api, jena

How can I determine object properties for a class in Jena . I  can get the all objects properties, but  I want to get the object properties for a particular class.

Code for getting all the objectProperties:

```
 ExtendedIterator objects = m.listObjectProperties();

  while (objects.hasNext()) 
       {
            Property essaProperty = (Property) objects.next();            
            System.out.println("Propiedad: " + essaProperty.getLocalName());

       }
```

Also, how I can get the related class to the object property, I mean, knowing A how I can get the object property "---->" and how I can get "B"

```
                                  has  
                             (A---------->B)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might find enough information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22814489/1281433) to [Parsing schema.org ttl/owl file using Jena](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22797424/1281433) to solve your problem, but if not, some discussion is in order.

First, note that properties in OWL are not the same kind of thing as "properties" in an object-oriented programming languages.  What it means we we say that a property P has a domain D is that when we see a statement whose property is P, we can infer that the subject is of type D.  As a rule, this is:

```
x P y      P rdfs:domain D
--------------------------
    x rdf:type D
```

But consider what this means.  If D is a subclass of C, then we can infer from `x rdf:type D` that `x rdf:type C`.  This means that `C` is *also* a domain of P.  (This is the case in OWL, but pure RDF has a slightly different semantics.)  Thus, if you're asking "what properties have class C as a domain", you'll get the properties that have subclasses of C as domains, in addition to properties that have C as a domain.

If you do want a sort of "object-oriented" view of the classes and properties, you can use the Jena method OntClass#listDeclaredProperties.

> ### [listDeclaredProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22814489/1281433)
>
> ```
> com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator<OntProperty> listDeclaredProperties(boolean direct)
> ```
>
> Return an iterator over the properties associated with a frame-like
>   view of this class. This captures an intuitive notion of the
>   properties of a class. This can be useful in presenting an ontology
>   class in a user interface, for example by automatically constructing a
>   form to instantiate instances of the class. The properties in the
>   frame-like view of the class are determined by comparing the domain of
>   properties in this class's OntModel with the class itself. See:
>   [Presenting RDF as frames][2] for more details.
>
> Note that many cases of determining whether a property is associated
>   with a class depends on RDFS or OWL reasoning. This method may
>   therefore return complete results only in models that have an attached
>   reasoner.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> - direct - If true, restrict the properties returned to those directly associated with this class. If false, the properties of super-classes
>     of this class will not be listed among the declared properties of this
>     class.
>
> #### Returns:
>
> An iteration of the properties that are associated with this class by their domain.

Comment: Hi @Joshua, thank you very much for your nice explanation. I'm looking for object oriented approach. As you said, just, I'm presenting the ontology class for a user interface.I have used com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator<OntProperty> listDeclaredProperties(boolean direct) and it works for me.  By using it, I got the domain (listDomain()) and range (listRange())